# Create site using code in Alfresco All in one project with Eclipse IDE

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How can i Create site using code in Alfresco All in one project.

I am using Eclipse IDE.

and I am going to build and deploy war file.

But After Deploying war, I want that one site or logical partition will automatically get created. means we no need to create it manually by any specific user. All the things should be done through code only.

Can anyone tell me what files will be required for this, and where do i need to place it in alfresco All in one project?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What do you think of CMIS or Rest Api ???

Comment: It will be better if Rest API, not CMIS

Comment: You can found how to work with it in https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5510-repository-restful-api-reference Are you interested in an answer ???

Comment: @Yagimi  Thanks, I will go through the link you provided. But it will be helpful if you provide answer also.

Comment: I will provide an answer and to wait for it , work with postman to try every script

Comment: @YagamiLight   Thank you So much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132686/discussion-between-deepak-talape-and-yagami-light).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer Below Code if you want to use CMIS API

```
      package com.kayne.cmis.webscript;
      import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
      import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
      import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
      import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
      import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
      import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity;
      import org.json.JSONObject;
      public class CreateSiteTest {   
      public static void main(String[] args){

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.getState().setCredentials(                
   new AuthScope("localhost", 8080, "Alfresco"),           
     new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin"));   
   String apiurl ="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites";
  PostMethod post = new PostMethod(apiurl);
  try {
     JSONObject site = new JSONObject();
     site.put("shortName", "kaynezhang");
     site.put("visibility", "PUBLIC");
      site.put("sitePreset", "site-dashboard");


     System.out.println(site.toString());
     post.setDoAuthentication(true);
     post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(site.toString(), "application/json",  "UTF-8"));


     int status = client.executeMethod(post);
         if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.err.println("Method failed: " + post.getStatusLine());
             } 
     String resultString = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
     System.out.println(resultString);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     post.releaseConnection();
  }   } }
```

You can learn more about the subject in [CMIS REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/pra/1/topics/cmis-welcome.html).

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
         var site = siteService.createSite("site-dashboard", "gamma-site", "Gamma Site", "A site description", siteService.PUBLIC_SITE, "st:site");
```

This might help you to create site at the repository level. This will return a Site object of the created site with the specified parameters.

Comment: can you tell me, at the repository level in which file i have to write this code?

Comment: Hi, It depends upon how do you want to create site. You can create webscript or dashlet to get the required parameters and allow users to create site.

Comment: I don't want to create it through user, I want to create it through bootstrap, when we deploy war file or amp file first time .